# How to fix continuous animation in jquery hover

Tags: jquery, hover

If you try to hover-in and hover-out on a green box, 5 times or more in a second, you will see that the box is bouncing like a ball. What I want to happen is that, when the green box goes back to its original size (50px) then hover-in will be enabled again. So that whenever I do faster `hover-in` and `hover-out` the animation will not look like bouncing.
Hope you get what I mean.
here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/qTyyA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because animation are pushed in a queue (not all animation are played at the same time) If you move very fast, a lot of animation is enqueue, and is played in the chronological order. This is a the normal behaviour.

If you want to fix this effect, you need to empty the queue of animation each time you begin another animation.

Use this code and you will have what you are expecting

```
$img.hover(
        function(){                
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
               height: o.contentHeight,
               width: o.contentWidth,
               left: "-=" + leftDistance,
               top: "-=" + topDistance
            }, o.speed);                
        }, 
        function(){
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
               height: o.imageInitHeight,
               width: o.imageInitWidth,
               left: "+=" + leftDistance,
               top: "+=" + topDistance
            }, o.speed);
        }            
    );
```

The `stop(true)` method will reset the queue of future animation.

Of course this will not solve the entire problem because you will now have a remaning problem with your position calculation.

You should review this part, and try to use something more simple with animation

Here is a working example: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qTyyA/3/)

Comment: Stopping at the mid of relative incremental operations will most likely break more stuff than fix anything.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté was right. http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/qTyyA/4/  But I like your solution. :)

Comment: Here is a clear example of working code http://jsfiddle.net/qTyyA/3/ It is more simple and do not break any stuff Fabricio :p

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your existing code and just disable the zoom in/out for X period of time after a full zoom in/out (not using `jQuery.stop()`), you can use the `data()` method to set a variable on the DOM element and use `setTimeout()` to clear it. In this example after the zoom out both actions will be disabled for 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

```
$img.hover(
    function(){
       // do not zoom in if currently disabled
       if (!$(this).data('disabled')){
            $(this).animate({
               height: o.contentHeight,
               width: o.contentWidth,
               left: "-=" + leftDistance,
               top: "-=" + topDistance
            }, o.speed);  
        }             
    }, 
    function(){
       // do not zoom out if currently disabled
         if (!$(this).data('disabled')){
            // disable zoom in/out by setting 'disabled=true'
            $(this).data('disabled', true);
            // alias this to a variable
            var $this = $(this);
            // use setTimeout to clear the variable after 1000ms
            setTimeout(function(){ $this.data('disabled', false); }, 1000);
            $(this).animate({
               height: o.imageInitHeight,
               width: o.imageInitWidth,
               left: "+=" + leftDistance,
               top: "+=" + topDistance
            }, o.speed);
        }
    }            
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still breaks some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To fix an issue like this you could take advantage of HoverIntent (Plugin).

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Simple to use and damn flexible.